# Setting up rbenv properly

Tags: bashrc

I have rvemv installed but every time I close terminal I'm required to execute `exec $SHELL` for it to reload `rvemv` otherwise I get an error that `rbemv` is not installed. How can I fix this so I don't need to execute exec $SHELL?

This is also included in my .bashrc:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a common issue. You should place them in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

**NOTE**: Make sure you don't have `~/.bash_profile` otherwise `~/.profile` will NOT be loaded by bash. This is Ubuntu Desktop default behaviour.

Alternatively, you can use an external script for rbenv, whenever needed, source it manually;-)

For example, rbenv.sh

```
#! /bin/sh
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```